# SQL Server 2016 weird behavior - OR condition gives 0 rows But AND condition gives some rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT T.tnum,
       T.secId,           
FROM   TradeCore T
       INNER JOIN Sec S
               ON S.secId = T.secId
       INNER JOIN TradeTransfer TT
               ON t.tnum = TT.tnum
WHERE  ( T.td >= '2019-01-01' )
       AND ( T.td <= '2019-02-25' )
       AND ( T.fundId = 3 OR TT.fundId = 3 )
       AND ( T.stratId = 7 OR TT.stratId = 7 ) --Line 1
    -- AND ( T.stratId = 7 AND TT.stratId = 7 ) --Line 2
```

When I keep last line commented I get 0 results, But when I un-comment it and comment the line before it, I get some result.

How is this possible?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190135/discussion-on-question-by-amit-kumar-sql-server-2016-weird-behavior-with-or-cond).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any row meeting `(T.stratId = 7 AND TT.stratId = 7)` must certainly meet `(T.stratId = 7 OR TT.stratId = 7)` so it is not logically possible that the less restrictive predicate returns less results.

The issue is a corrupt non clustered index.

**And Case**

- 154 rows in `TradeCore` matching the date condition and stratId = 7 are emitted.
- Join on `TradeTransfer` with the `stratId` and `fundId` conditions applied ouputs 68 rows (estimated 34 rows)
- These all successfully join onto a row in `Sec` (using index IX_Sec_secId_sectype_Ccy_valpoint) and 68 rows are returned as the final result.

[image]

**Or case**

- 1173 rows in `TradeCore` matching the date condition are emitted
- Join on `TradeTransfer` with a residual predicate on `3 in (T.fundId, TT.fundId) AND 7 in (T.stratId, TT.stratId)` brings this down to 73 (estimated 297 rows)
- Then all rows are eliminated by the join on Sec - despite the fact that we know from above that at least 68 of them have a match.

[image]

The table cardinality of `Sec` is `2399` rows. In the plan where all rows are removed by the join SQL Server does a full scan on `IX_Sec_idu` as input to the probe side of the hash join but the full scan on that index *only returns 589 rows*.

The rows that appear in the other execution plan are pulled from a different index that contains these 1,810 missing rows.

You have confirmed in the comments that the following return differing results

```
select count(*) from Sec with(index = IX_Sec_idul); --589 
select count(*) from Sec with(index = IX_Sec_secId_sectype_Ccy_valpoint); --2399
select count(*) from Sec with(index = PK_Sec)  --2399
```

This should never be the case that rowcounts from different indexes on the same table don't match (except if an index is filtered and that does not apply here).

### Reason for different indexes

Because the row estimates going in to the join on `Sec` in the `AND` case are only 34 it chooses a plan with nested loops and therfore needs an index with leading column `secId` to perform a seek. For the `OR` case it estimates 297 rows and instead of doing an estimated 297 seeks it chooses a hash join instead so selects the smallest index available containing the `secId` column.

### Fix

As all rows exist in the clustered index you can drop `IX_Sec_idul` and create it again to hopefully resolve this issue (take a backup first).

You should also run `dbcc checkdb` to see if any other issues are lurking.