# Getting duplicate rows when adding order by statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a MS SQL database that was created from a script from another database. This DB has states table with the following columns:

```
state_id
state_name
state_abb
state_lat
state_long
```

When I do a simple query like:

```
select * from states
```

I get back 51 rows with no dupes.

When I add, `order by state_name asc`, I get a duplicate record each row/

Any idea why this is happening? When I run the same queries in the original database it works as expected.

Comment: order by does not add duplicates. Review the 51 rows result properly, you will see duplicated rows, the thing is that, given they were not ordered, you are not noticing the dups

Comment: And 51 sounds correct assuming this is US states and it includes District of Columbia.

Comment: 51 is correct.....when I view my dropdown that is connected to this database I see the dupes......I have other databases with that same code that works as expected, this is very odd, I can add district and it works as expected

Comment: There is a 0% chance that adding an order by to a query produces more rows. Are you seeing dupes in the dropdown because you are adding items to it more than once? Doesn't sound like this is a sql server issue so much as an issue with application code.

Comment: I thought the same thing, so I am running the sql statement directly in MS SQL Server management studio and I get the dupes

Comment: figured it out, sorry to bother you guys, I must have imported the states info into that tables after the db was created and that created the dupes.

Comment: Ok then use "group by state_name" in your query.

Comment: @SeanLange `0.0001%` chance perhaps. It would not be impossible if corruption was present and the `order by` caused a different index to be used. (similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55183714/sql-server-2016-weird-behavior-or-condition-gives-0-rows-but-and-condition-giv/55185632#55185632)

Comment: And fix your schema - duplicates should, quite simply, not be possible. Mistakes like this can easily be prevented.